# While doing "from pymatgen.core.io.cif import CifParser" in PYMATGEN i got this error

Tags: python, pymatgen

[error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDBVR.png)

I was trying to convert cif file into Pwscf file for Quantum Espresso.

Comment: In the future, please post the error message as a text rather than posting a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change that line to `from pymatgen.io.cif import CifParser` and it should work fine.